# Nginx warning "conflicting server name <domain_name> on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored"

Tags: nginx, ghost

I have looked across several forums and StackOverflow questions but I'm truly at a loss here as to why this is not working.

I was running a Ghost.org blog on a Digital Ocean droplet and had configured it according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-blog-with-ghost-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04). I took a snapshot and destroyed the droplet a week ago. Everything is working fine at this moment.

Today, I created a fresh droplet with the same snapshot. Since the IP was different, I modified the domain settings accordingly and it was reflected on my computer as well.
Then I try to access the website but the connection times out. Even after an hour or so, it times out, so I figures it's not DNS propogation at fault. A simple check on whatsmydns.net also confirms this is not the issue.

Upon further investigation, I find that `/var/log/nginx/error.log` has the following line in it - the only one for today's date:

`2016/05/29 16:32:10 [warn] 988#0: conflicting server name "foobar.com.tld" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`

I have checked the two configs I know could conflict - `nginx.conf` and `sites-enabled/ghost` (symlink to `sites-available/ghost`) for any conflicts - and I can't seem to find any.

I am not very comfortable with nginx - this is really my first exposure to it, but I've been banging my head for over 2.5 hours now and would really appreciate some help.

`nginx.conf`: http://pastebin.com/YUhBZVhX
`sites-enabled/ghost`: http://pastebin.com/3cdZgTG3
`www/ghost/config.js`: http://pastebin.com/iunffMzN

**Edit**: `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` folder is empty, so there isn't a conflict there.

**Edit 2**: The simplest config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foobar.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }
}
```

doesn't seem to work either. I did restart the `nginx` service after making this change and also modified Ghost's `config.js` accordingly and restarted its service.

**Edit 3**: There are no hidden or backup files in the `sites-enabled` folder.

Comment: Check sites-enabled folder for backup or hisden files

Comment: @AlexeyTen No hidden or backup files.

Comment: Check with recursive grep on whole /etc/nginx folder. There is no magic, there should be conflicting file somewhere

Comment: I found a couple of .save files under sites-available using recursive grep. Removing them and restarting nginx didn't help either. Could the problem not be nginx but something else? How do I make sure I know that nginx is working fine?

Comment: FWIW, I had a record in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/ftp.conf file. It drove me mad for a while...

Answer (score 0):

Once you've confirmed that `foobar.com` isn't used in `server_name` anywhere else in your Nginx configs, look for `$hostname` or other Nginx variable, whose value might match your `server_name`:

[Alphabetical index of Nginx variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html)

**Example:**

```
server {
    server_name localhost $hostname;
    listen 80;

    access_log off;
}
```

Got me puzzled there for a while.